# Simulate data from lognormal in R

Tags: r, simulation

Suppose I want to simulate 10 observations from lognormal distribution and repeat this 100 times. I wrote some R code, but for some reason it's not working. Here is the code:

```
for(i in 1:100) 
 {

x = rlnorm(10, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)

 }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You are overwriting `x` at each iteration of the loop. You might want to look at `replicate(100, rlnorm(10, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1))`

Comment: Or more simply, `x <- matrix(rlnorm(1000, m = 0, s = 1), nrow = 100)`. Then the vector of sample means could be gotten with `rowMeans(x)` and the standard deviation vector could be obtained with `apply(m, 1, sd)`. If you want them bound together, `DF <- data.frame(mean = rowMeans(x), sd = apply(m, 1, sd))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could work:

```
lapply(1:100, function(i) rlnorm(10, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1))
```

**EDIT**
To calculate the mean and sd use:

```
lapply(1:100, function(i) {
    x <- rlnorm(10, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)
    c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x))
})
```

Or to return it in a matrix format (use `do.call`):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:100, function(i) {
    x <- rlnorm(10, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)
    c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x))
}))
```

And also to make your original code work (see DWin's note) use:

```
x <- list()
for(i in 1:100) {
    x[[i]] <- rlnorm(10, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)
}
```

Comment: How can I calculate the mean and sd for each 10 observations? Thanks!

Comment: See my edit.  Note you could also use `lapply` on the first creation and supply `function(x) c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x))` to it after creating the 100 simulations.