# Simulate from an (arbitrary) continuous probability distribution

Tags: r, random, distribution

For a normalized probability density function defined on the real line, for example

```
p(x) = (2/pi) * (1/(exp(x)+exp(-x))
```

(this is just an example; the solution should apply for any continuous PDF we can define) is there a package in R to simulate from the distribution? I am aware of R's built-in simulators for many distributions.

I could numerically compute the inverse cumulative distribution function at a set of quantiles, store them in a table, and use the table to map from uniform variates to variates from the desired distribution. Is there already a package that does this?

Comment: Google suggested [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1594121/324364).

Comment: Thanks, that question and mine are indeed the same.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508400/generating-random-sample-from-the-quantiles-of-unknown-density-in-r/20509483#20509483) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258482/use-inverse-cdf-to-generate-random-variable-in-r/23259123#23259123), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223548/how-can-i-generate-a-sample-from-a-log-normal-distribution-with-pareto-tail-in-r/23228354#23228354).

Comment: Actually, your question and the Google reference in @joran's comment  *not* the same. Your are asking if there is a package in R to do this. There was no package in 2009, when that question was asked and answered. But there is now (see my response below). IMO this is a *perfect example* of why embargoing questions as "duplicated" is a really horrible practice (although no one is suggesting that for your question).

Comment: @jlhoward , good point, although then we get into a "close because asking to recommend a package" situation ... (it's not entirely clear to me that this close criterion should really be as applicable for [r] as it is for other tags ...)

Comment: @jlhoward In my defense, I simply provided what assistance I could in a comment. I never voted to close until the OP _explicitly_ said that the linked question was a duplicate. Frankly, the best solution would be for your answer to be on the old question, and for this to be closed as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @BenBolker Yes I know. Still I think expecting someone to come across the `distr` package by accident is a pretty big lift. If you google "distr in R" you get nothing about this package.

Comment: @joran Sorry if this came across as directed at you personally - it was definitely *not* intended that way. I just believe embargoing questions as duplicates is a really bad practice in general, and this was (IMO) one good example of why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way using the `distr` package, which is designed for this.

```
library(distr)
p    <- function(x) (2/pi) * (1/(exp(x)+exp(-x)))  # probability density function
dist <-AbscontDistribution(d=p)  # signature for a dist with pdf ~ p
rdist <- r(dist)                 # function to create random variates from p

set.seed(1)                      # for reproduceable example
X <- rdist(1000)                 # sample from X ~ p
x <- seq(-10,10, .01)
hist(X, freq=F, breaks=50, xlim=c(-5,5))
lines(x,p(x),lty=2, col="red")
```

[image]

You can of course also do this is base R using the methodology described in any one of the links in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the function that you're dealing with, you could just take the integral (or, if you're rusty on your integration rules like me, you could use a tool like Wolfram Alpha to [do it for you](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282/pi%29%20*%20%281/%28exp%28x%29%2bexp%28-x%29%29%29)).

In the case of the function provided, you can simulate with:

```
draw.val <- function(numdraw) log(tan(pi*runif(numdraw)/2))
```

A histogram confirms that we're sampling correctly:

```
hist(draw.val(10000), breaks=100, probability=T)
x <- seq(-10, 10, .001)
lines(x, (2/pi) * (1/(exp(x)+exp(-x))), col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the particular form of p(x) I showed was just an example.