# Composite lognormal Pareto distribution

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

For the model I am working on in NetLogo, I would like to distribute a certain variable X as a composite lognormal-pareto, which takes a lognormal density up to an unknown threshold value *θ* and a two-parameter Pareto density with scaling parameter *α* thereafter.

The pdf is the following:

f1(x) = (αθ^α / (1+Φ(k))x^(α+1))exp{(-α^2/2k^2)ln^2(x/θ)} , 0 < x ≤ θ

f2(x) = αθ^α / (1+Φ(k))x^(α+1). , θ < x < ∞

where Φ(·) is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution and k is a constant.

How can I write this in NetLogo?

Comment: @JenB A composite lognormal-Pareto distribution takes a lognormal density up to an unknown threshold value θ, and a two-parameter Pareto density with scaling parameter α thereafter. The idea of such a composite model comes from Cooray and Ananda (2005).

Comment: I have edited my question. I hope it provides enough information now

Comment: I am not sure, if I get your problem. But do you have to do the calculation in NetLogo? Or could you just do your calculation in another software and have as an output value a value that shows the amount of X per patch in a way that your expectations are matched?
That might help to split your question into two parts which could be answered by different persons and it simplifies your problem.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do (R solution)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223548/how-can-i-generate-a-sample-from-a-log-normal-distribution-with-pareto-tail-in-r

Comment: Yes, the only difference is that I would need to build a report function that returns a lognormal-pareto distributed number

Comment: @SilviaLeoni NetLogo doesn't have an integrate function (though I guess you could write one) so it might be easiest to use the R function in that answer and use the R extension in NetLogo to access it.